# cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes

Tags: git, github

Today at the office I got a weird error while using `git pull`, but here is what happened.

1. I cloned the repo: `git clone <repo-url>`
2. Applied my modifications
3. Staged modified/created files in step 2: `git add <file(s)>`
4. `git commit -m "my message"`
5. `git pull --rebase`

and I got the following error:

```
error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: please commit or stash them.
```

When looking at the commit with `git show <SHA>` I can see my staged files. Just FYI between step 1 and 5 some code was pushed.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not weird: it means just what it says. Perhaps you missed a file or two in your `git add` step 3.

Comment: You can also do `git pull --rebase --autostash`, that will stash, then pull with rebase, then pop the stash.

Comment: Git status , to check the list of unstaged files. There should be some missing files yet to be committed. Also If you have done a push in between , then try reset HEAD^1 to redo again

Answer (score 0):

Note that this specific error message will be gone with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021):

See [commit 7050791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/705079112669c05c7ce5dee38ee8d7f075b8b3cf), [commit 2963395](https://github.com/git/git/commit/296339549a52ee17c8e61429c081ac17fe81ac26), [commit be8d370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8d370e3c0791e8b181ddc73cce37ff8356257c), [commit 162410f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/162410f8a020dc039ead88c0ec5337ed808b7019) (11 Sep 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 57e4a7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57e4a7b633d00f274051d436edcec14ad98969c3), 23 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-sh-setup`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be8d370e3c0791e8b181ddc73cce37ff8356257c): remove unused "pull with rebase" message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Remove the "`pull with rebase`" message previously used by the git-pull.sh script, which was removed in [49eb8d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49eb8d39c78f161231e63293df60f343d208f409) ("Remove contrib/examples/*", 2018-03-25, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd94dd02a6a0c286473204a317e38a8d0e6cd745) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26e47e261e969491ad4e3b6c298450c061749c9e)).
>
> Even if some out-of-tree user copy/pasted the old git-pull.sh code, and relied on passing it a "pull with rebase" argument, we'll fall back on the "*" case here, they just won't get the "pull with rebase" part of their message translated.
>
> I don't think it's likely that anyone out-of-tree relied on that, but I'm being conservative here per the discussion that can be found upthread of [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/87tuiwjfvi.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/).

Answer (score -1):

If you did it with the filesopened, try to close before. I alread had the same issue. ;)